# What could be causing this slow fetch in react native?

Tags: react-native

In the following code, the first console.log message prints pretty much instantly.  Then everything just hangs (I'm initially assumed it was waiting for the body of the response to be returned).  The Body of the response is only about 26K, the time waiting seems to be indefinite UNLESS, I shake the phone and interact with the debug menu.  As soon as I interact with the debug menu, the promise resolves and everything moves along as expected.  My interactions with the debug menu can be simple, like hide inspector, show inspector, just takes something to kick the promise resolution into gear and everything is fine.

```
fetch(SEARCH_URL, requestBody)
    .then((response) => {console.log(response); return response.json();})
    .then((responseData) => {
        debugger
        ...
```

Note:
Disconnecting from the debugger and running the code does not exhibit the slowness (and not being connected to the debugger ignores the debugger statements)

And yes, I have rebooted the computer.

Might have found something in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using `react-native` v0.24.1 and it only happens in Chrome Debugging. I do not believe this is related to issue 6679 that you link to. I think it is related to the async scheduling or setTimeout and fetch/promise implementation specific to Chrome. Keep in mind that when debugging in Chrome the JS of your RN app is completely run in the browser. There are shims and libraries in place to make the two environments behave the same. I think there is an issue with one of those pieces. This might be a good question to ask on the RN Facebook group.

Comment: @sstur is right, it is because of Chrome Debugging. Disable chrome debugging and you have good perf again.

Comment: @gre: yes, we can disable Chrome debugging and get good perf again. but this is totally a bug. It would be nice to track it down and see what exactly is causing it so a fix can be planned. Maybe GH issue for RN would be appropriate. Not sure.

Comment: This is for sure a bug, see the issue link above.

Comment: What I have found to make my app more responsive is to process the response inside a separate function and to call that function using a setTimeout call with 10ms or something. Since it then happens in the background (sort of) my app is more responsive.


Seems to have to have reduced loading time from 6 seconds to about 3 seconds for me.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found out yourself, this is a known bug that [should be fixed in react-native v0.31](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679#issuecomment-232672252)

Comment: It has been promised to be fixed in just about every version after 0.24, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: it is happening on rn39 as well

Comment: it seems that the same happens with 0.71

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug that parsing responses can lag badly when remote debugging is enabled. Disabling remote debugging should speed this up a lot.

You can [read the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679) for details and other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is moving the fetch calls inside the constructor of a react component. Otherwise they never resolve. Hope this helps

Comment: this could rather be a comment  than an answer

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I ended up setting the state of the data array to an empty array before re-fetching, as for me it would be slow only on refreshes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUsers([]);

    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}comp/main/`,
        {
            headers:{
                'X-API-KEY':userKey
            }
        })
                .then(response => {
                    setUsers(response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .finally(() => { setLoading(false),setRefreshing(false) });

}, [refreshReducer]);
```