# React Native Fetch: second promise hanging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-native, fetch-api

Strange problem with React Native's fetch.
It was working previously, not sure what I've changed but it's stopped working.

```
login(data,success,fail){
    console.log('doing fb login');
    fetch(host+'/api/login?credentials='+data.credentials)
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log('got login response');
            return response.json();
        } )
        .then( json => {
            console.log('got login json');
            if(json.result!='fail'){
                success(json);
            } else {
                fail(json);
            }
            return json;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.warn(error);
        });
}
```

The issue is I see the first 'got login response' message, but then it just hangs, and nothing happens until I press the screen upon which it fires the 'got login json' and continues as expected.

It's frustrating because this is happening consistently and I can't see why the second .then() isn't firing automatically.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: found a similar question: [What could be causing this slow fetch in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262456/what-could-be-causing-this-slow-fetch-in-react-native)

seems it is already being looked at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6679

Also the behaviour is only seen whne the Chrome debug tools are enabled... interesting

Comment: same thing happened to me and stopped happening when I disabled debugging through Chrome dev tools. Thank you so much for mentioning that part, saved me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could be causing this slow fetch in react native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262456/what-could-be-causing-this-slow-fetch-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

[response.json() is a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), not a value. So it won't resolve for you.
I would also check result based on response.status instead of json.result because for some case server's response won't convertible to json (401 for example).

```
.then( (response) => {
   if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      response.json().then((data) => success(data));
   } else {
      fail(response);
   }
})
```

Comment: Returning a promise from a `then` function is supposed to resolve the promise before chaining to the next `then` function, so you shouldn't have to nest `then` calls like that: `fetch(...).then(r => r.json()).then(d => /* process d */)` is a perfectly appropriate way of handling it.

Answer (score -1):

console.log is a blocking statement. A synchrone that stop the code until it is resolved but using with Chrome Debug it can be slow when the tab is not in foreground.